# Property returns undefined even though the value exists...?

Tags: javascript

I have this object `resources`:

```
var resources = { //Handles resources of all kinds.
    number: 100,
    money: 23000000,
    science: 1000,
    popularity: {
        amount: 0,
        upgProd: 0 //Amount produced from upgrades.
    }

};
```

This looks like a normal object. 
However, I'm trying to display a certain quantity `popularity`. Every time I try to display it, I get a NaN instead of a number.
I try to return `console.log(resources.popularity.upgProd);` but I still end up getting an `undefined`. I have no clue why since I define the variable but I still get undefined...
No errors in the IDE or in the console, just `undefined` when I console.log().

EDIT: Here is some surrounding context... this is my `update` function, that updates every 1/7 second. ALSO, the first value of `resources.popularity.upgProd` is 0, then the next become NaN.

```
function update() {
buffer++;
if (buffer == 35) {
checkVisibilityOnBuildings();
checkVisiblityOnUpgrades();
checkVisibilityOnResources();
buffer = 0;
} // Every 5 seconds (35 ticks) visibility will be checked and updated.

    /* Number increasing. A bit tedious but no other way to do it yet. */
    resources.number += 
   ((BUILDINGS[0].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[0].count) + //Now it's easy! Just do UPGRADES[n+1] for the next building.
    (BUILDINGS[1].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[1].count) +
    (BUILDINGS[2].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[2].count) +
    (BUILDINGS[3].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[3].count));
    //Science gained per tick. Var used to make the "scienceProductionTotalDisp" work properly
    var scienceTotalPerTick = 
    (BUILDINGS[2].sciProdBase * BUILDINGS[2].count) + 
    (BUILDINGS[3].sciProdBase * BUILDINGS[3].count);

    resources.science += scienceTotalPerTick;



    //Display vars for html so that rounding errors don't happen.
    var numDisp = Math.floor(resources.number);
    var sciDisp = Math.floor(resources.science * 100) / 100;
    var popDisp = Math.floor(resources.popularity.amount * 100) / 100;
    console.log(Number(resources.popularity.upgProd));
    var moneyTotalPerTick = Math.pow(resources.number, (1/(player.moneyRatio))) + 1; //Cash flow per 143ms (7n for total / sec ish)
    var popularityTotalPerTick = (Number(resources.popularity.upgProd)) + 0;
    resources.popularity += popularityTotalPerTick;
    console.log(resources.popularity.upgProd);
    resources.money += moneyTotalPerTick;
    getId('moneyProductionTotalDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(Math.floor(moneyTotalPerTick * 7));
    getId('moneyDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(Math.round(resources.money * 100) / 100);
    getId('numberDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(numDisp);
    getId('scienceDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(sciDisp);
    getId('popularityDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(popDisp);
    getId('scienceProductionTotalDisp').innerHTML = 
numFormat(Math.floor(scienceTotalPerTick * 700) / 100);
    getId('popularityProductionTotalDisp').innerHTML = 
numFormat(Math.floor(popularityTotalPerTick * 700) / 100);
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem does not appear to be in the code you posted - is `resources` *really* populated statically and at once? You might post more surrounding context

Comment: `console.log(resources.popularity);`?

Comment: when you get NaN ?

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a different `resources` variable in scope when you come to print out.

Comment: Do you take any modification on `resources`, such as pass it into a function, before calling console.log?

Comment: too few event. You might post more surrounding context

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The error is on other lines of code.

Comment: I posted the other lines of code that are causing issues.

Comment: There is your problem: `resources.popularity += popularityTotalPerTick;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your problem:

`resources.popularity += popularityTotalPerTick;`

popularity is an object, and that doesn't do what you want.

Since you overwrite it with the result of an object added by a value, you assign it s string `[object Object]9` where the last digit is whatever was in popularityTotalPerTick.

You get `NaN` (Not a number) since you are using `Number(x)`in `console.log(Number(resources.popularity.upgProd));`. Why are you doing that?

Does `getId` do a lookup of the element in the dom every time your function is called? Have the object changed or are you querying the DOM for the same element 7 times per second?

---

Some thoughts about the other tings in your code:

```
resources.number +=
    ((BUILDINGS[0].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[0].count) +
        (BUILDINGS[1].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[1].count) +
        (BUILDINGS[2].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[2].count) +
        (BUILDINGS[3].numProdBase * BUILDINGS[3].count));
```

I'm assuming that BUILDINGS is an array with all the buildings, and that you want to calculate the number of all buildings in the array. There is a function for that: [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) that takes two parameters: a function and the start value:

```
resources.number += // do you really want += here and not just = ?
  BUILDINGS.reduce( (sum, item) => sum + (item.numProdBase * item.count), 0 );
```

If your aren't familiar with arrow-functions it could be replaced with:

```
function (sum, item) { return sum + (item.numProdBase * item.count) }
```

---

```
var scienceTotalPerTick = 
    (BUILDINGS[2].sciProdBase * BUILDINGS[2].count) + 
    (BUILDINGS[3].sciProdBase * BUILDINGS[3].count);
```

I'm not sure why you are only doing it for two buildings, and not for all, but you could use reduce here too, with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Slice)

```
var scienceTotalPerTick =
  BUILDINGS.slice(2,4).reduce( (sum, item) => sum + (item.sciProdBase * item.count), 0);
```

Notice that the parameters to slice is *begin* to *end* (**end not included**), therefor 2,4 gives you element 2 and 3.

---

With this part of the code...

```
getId('moneyProductionTotalDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(Math.floor(moneyTotalPerTick * 7));
getId('moneyDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(Math.round(resources.money * 100) / 100);
getId('numberDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(numDisp);
getId('scienceDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(sciDisp);
getId('popularityDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(popDisp);
```

I assume that *getId* is a function that fetches the element via *document.getElementById* or *document.querySelector*, and that you do this for every frame, and you get the same element every time. Now imagine that the element is a box, and that I demand that you get it from the warehouse that is on the other side of the world. When you deliver the box, I open the box, replace the contents and send it back to the warehouse on the other side of the world. When you come back, I demand that you get the same box again, and you now have to travel to the other side of the world once again... and when you come back the story repeats...

My point here is that it is very wasteful to travel to the other side of the world each time to get the same box, or to get the same element from the DOM at each update. You could cache the elements by looking them up ONE time before you start the update, and you can put the result in an object:

```
function getElementsToUpdate() {
  return {
    moneyProductionTotalDisp: getId('moneyProductionTotalDisp'),
    moneyDisp: getId('moneyDisp'),
    // and so on...
  }
}
```

If you name the property in the object the same as the id, you can put all the names in an array, and then reduce it to an object. This saves you some typing, and hard to find bugs because of a misspelled name:

```
function getElementsToUpdate() {
  return [
    'moneyProductionTotalDisp',
    'moneyDisp',
    'numberDisp',
    'scienceDisp',
    'popularityDisp',
    // and so on....
  ].reduce(
    (out, id) => { out[id] = getId(id); return out; }, {}
  )
}
```

NOTE: This function should be run ONE time at startup, not for every update of the frame. It returns an object with the elements.

Somewhere in your code I assume that you use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to call your *update* function. Since *setInteval* can take extra parameters that will be given to the called function, you can do something like this:

```
var timerHandle = setInterval( update, 1000/7, getElementsToUpdate() );
```

where *update* is your function, *1000/7* gives you the interval for 7 times a second, and *getElementsToUpdate* is the function that makes the time-expensive call to get the elements from the DOM **one** time.

You need to change the update function to take a parameter (the name is not important, but should be short and descriptive, so I use *elem*). This is the object that *getElementsToUpdate()* have returned with all the html-elements.

```
function update(elem) {
  // ... your code ....

  // Old code, that makes an expensive lookup into the DOM, and start a HTML parser.
  // getId('numberDisp').innerHTML = numFormat(numDisp);

  // New code, that gets the pre-looked up element and set the text.  
  elem.numberDisp.textContent = numFormat(numDisp);
}
```

---

I'm not a fan of using *.innerHTML* when it isn't html that is inserted. Always use *.textContent* instead, if is isn't html. In this case it would be better if you use the [output](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output)-element, and set the *.value* property.

Comment: Thank you so much!

And yes the object changes every 1/7 second, since every tick you get a certain amount of each resource which is then reflected.

Comment: @JackGoodman Have the object you get with `getId` changed every 1/7 second? Or are you executing a very time-consuming function to get the same element over and over and over and over...?

Comment: The object hasn't changed, only the value of one of its properties. How would I fix that?
If you're talking about the html object (which I don't think you are?) then that gets updated 7 times a second. The javascript object doesn't change except for the properties of each resource in my RESOURCES object.

Comment: So when I use the function `getElementsToUpdate()`, would I then have to make an object for what it's returning and call that object every frame? Currently by just running the function once it will only update every time I perform an action (click something).

Comment: Also @some I'm getting an assigning to rvalue error when I use the last function. Looking at why that is right now.

Comment: You should USE the object that *getElementsToUpdate()* returns, not CALL it every time. See my updated answer. I hope that I made it clearer.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

try using `console.log(resources["popularity"]["upgProd"])`

Comment: what are you getting for console.log(resources.popularity) ?

Comment: This is javascript, not php, and it is perfectly alright, and preferred to write `resouces.popularity.upgProd`